# recipe for target '"Proyecto 4.o"' failed

Tags: c++

Hi i am having the following error in dev-c++5.11 con windows10

`LINE 28        C:\Users\Desktop\Makefile.win   recipe for target '"Proyecto 4.o"' failed`

Makefile line28:

`$(CPP) -c "Proyecto 4.cpp" -o "Proyecto 4.o" $(CXXFLAGS)`

even with the most basic like ...

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout<<"Hello";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this the complete error message? Have you installed a compiler?

Comment: If yes, that's the error message the compiler is getting. In windows I only get a "g++.exe application error" sign. I use the same compiler that Dev-C ++ 5.11 brings, I already tried to reinstall Dev-C ++ and install a newer version of TDM-GCC but it did nothing.

Comment: What happens when you try to build your file from terminal?

Comment: g++.exe - Application error
the application failed to start correctly (0xc0000142).

Comment: Does this help? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/error-0xc0000142/3da27a75-178c-4de5-b43c-c538e6005540